# Qt Serial Communictaion - communicating with a stm32f0 board over Putty

Tags: qt, stm32, qtserialport

I need to create a Qt GUI that enables the user to select an option from a comboBox and on pressing a 'send' button, send some data to a STM32f072-Disco board via Serial Communication ( over a COM Port - COM11). I looked at the Qt blockig master, blocking slva eexamples but don't understand them very clearly. Any suggestions on how I can proceed ?

Comment: You need to be more specific for people to help you. Writing to serial is pretty straight forward in Qt but without any details or code it will be difficult to provide any solution to your problem.

Comment: I need to send data in sets of 8 bytes - hex values... I am using the CDC driver on the stm32 so I have a comms port.. Curently I can send bytes to the board via input from putty.  I need some suggestion on how to use Serial port in Qt

Comment: Well i will provide a general example

Comment: That would be a good start @tobilocker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to make a Qt application with some help from sources on github.. The application is able to send & read data from the stm32 board. The stm32 dev board is configured as a CDC device. 
The library provided @ https://brosnanyuen.blogspot.in/2016/06/stm32-usb-cdc-vcp.html is useful for CDC communication as the stm32 middleware is slightly complex to use. 
The git repor @ https://github.com/WalkingFrog/Qt-SerialPort-Programming-Demo is a good start for beginners looking for a start. 
I can share my code on any requets.